# What is the difference between DNS hosting settings and DNS setting in Direct Admin control panel

Tags: dns, web-hosting, cpanel

I hosted my blog at a web space with cPanel, but I am confused with the DNS settings. I bought my domain in namecheap and setting dns server to Point DNS.

What is the relationship between DNS setting in DNS hosting service and DNS settings inside cPanel (such as "Advanced DNS Zone Editor" and "Simple DNS Zone Editor"). Will DNS setting in Point DNS overcome settings in cPanel? Or more complicated than that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recommendation regarding DNS.

**Less than 10 Domains/Simple Usage: Use Registrar's DNS**

If you are hosting less than 10 domains and they are all your domains, use your provider's DNS service. That just makes things easier for you.

**Over 10 Domains, Reselling, Frequent Changes: Use Server's DNS**

If you are hosting more than 10 domains, add domains frequently, or re-selling hosting services, then you will need your own nameservers.  There are several steps here. First you must configure cPanel to be used as a nameserver, then list these nameservers/hosts at your registrar, and finally, setup your domain to use the nameservers you selected.

**Use DNS Provider**

There are benefits to using a 3rd party DNS provider such as UltraDNS, DNS Made Easy or similar providers.  These providers often have a global reach with their networks. This improves DNS propagation, speeds up DNS lookups, and reduces DNS outages.  If you run a site that makes you money, consider these services.  Despite having the know how and more than a 150 servers, we still outsource our DNS.

References:

cPanel Docs

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/WHMDocs/BasicSetup#Nameservers

Flash Tutorial

http://www.rackaid.com/flash/whm11-setup-voice/whm-setup-17-nameservers.html

Flash Tutorial

http://www.rackaid.com/flash/whm11-services-voice/whm-services-22-dnszones.html